# when are all comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

After reading this question: [Comments deleted in question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34268/comments-deleted-in-question) I think the reason for deleting all comments is when so much of them are rude or offensive.

But this question: [What does the number near a comment mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220799/what-does-the-number-near-a-comment-mean) didn't have any rude or flagged comments so why are all comments deleted in it?

Comment: Comments are deleted for any reason.  Click the comment flag button to see the options you have, but basically if too many comments are off-topic, rude, obsolete, spam, etc, then a mod may decide to delete everything rather than the individual comments.

Comment: I'm going to guess mods have a one click remove all comments button. Usually, removing all comments indicates an unprofessional or otherwise off-topic discussion in the comments.

Comment: Sometimes mode go on a rampage.

Comment: Sometimes when there are lots of comments and many are bad, it's easier for moderator to just swipe them all clean instead of reading one by one and selecting only the bad comments. We should know that comments are temporary and any important information must be added to the post itself. If you remember a post having important comment you can flag the post itself, choose "Other" and ask to undelete such comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All comments are deleted if every user who's commented on a post decides to delete all their comments or if a moderator decides to delete every comment made by all users. The two methods are not mutually exclusive.

There are any number of reasons for doing this but they're probably best summed up by the flagging options:

- rude or offensive
- not constructive
- too chatty
- obsolete

So, yes; if all the comments were rude then a moderator might remove them all. But, it's equally possible I had a conversation with you in the comments to clarify your post. Then, edited the information into the post, deleted all my comments, asked you to do the same, and requested that a moderator remove all your comments when you didn't. Or, maybe we've been having a conversation about breakfast and someone else requested that a moderator remove them our comments.

Or, maybe there just weren't any comments to begin with...

Comment: worth noting that moderators are capable to clarify details of comments deletion if needed, as [they can see deleted comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85469/165773 "feature implemented per this request")